# Kohana 3.3 model Class Not Found error only in php 5.5.3

Tags: php, kohana-orm, ubuntu-13.10

I am writing a Kohana app that has been dev'd locally on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (PHP 5.3). It works without issue in this environment, but it throws a fatal error whenever it tries to autoload a classes/Model class on the production server (which is Ubuntu 13.10 running PHP 5.5). The application code is exactly the same. The only difference I could mention is that the apache vhost conf uses the Require directive instead of the Allow/Deny syntax because Ubuntu 13.10 ships with newer version of apache.

I get the following error whenever I hit a controller action that needs to load a model:

ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_Event' not found
MODPATH/orm/classes/Kohana/ORM.php [ 46 ]

Interestingly enough, Kohana is evidently able to load the controller classes I wrote without issue.

[source root]/application/classes/Model/Event.php exists and is ugo+rx (as are the parent directories). It contains a valid class definition (this works without issue on my local 12.04/5.3 environment). 'head -n2 [source root]/application/classes/Model/Event.php' is:

`<?
class Model_Event extends Model_BaseModel {`

I know PHP 5.5 introduced a difference in how it does case-insensitive string comparisons, but the file/folder names and class names are an exact case match so this shouldn't be an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

PHP wasn't respecting the "short_open_tag = On" ini setting.